# How do I use multiple If's in Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a UFO in my ROBLOX place, and wanted to create a system that would play an audio when the UFO passes overhead. I created a part, inserted an audio into the part, then placed a script in the audio. So it looks like:

Part->Audio->Script

I plan the system to register when a Humanoid is touched, and if the part is going faster than say, 300 Studs per second, I want it to play an audio (preferably the audio would be played only for the person(s) that was touched by the part) so I wrote a script that goes as follows:

```
while true do
    if script.parent.parent.Velocity.Magnitude>299 then 
        script.Parent:play()
        wait(5)
        script.Parent:stop()
    else
        wait()
    end
    wait()
end
```

As you can see I'm missing the part about the humanoid being touched, but I'm not sure how to write that. I'm really new to scripting, and I don't know the proper context for these commands. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Lua's logical operators: 'and', 'or', and 'not' are the most commonly used. In your case, it sounds like you want to do something like:

```
if (condition1) and (condition2) then
    play_sound()
else
    wait()
end
```

You can also "nest" if statements:

```
if condition1 then
    if condition2 then
        do_something()
    end
end
```

Comment: So my script so far is:

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Will's answer you could also use `elseif` to check different conditions.

```
if (conditionA) then
elseif (conditionB) then
end
```

If conditionA is true, the next statements will not be checked, thus order is important.

```
while true do
if script.parent.parent.Velocity.Magnitude>299 then 
 if(humanoidIsTouchedd()) then
    script.Parent:play()
    wait(5)
    script.Parent:stop()
 elseif (somethingElseIsTouched())
    doSomethingElse()
 else
    wait()
end
wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you use this:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Tounched:Connect(function(hit)
    if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") script.parent.parent.Velocity.Magnitude < 299 or then return end
end)
script.Parent:play()
    wait(5)
    script.Parent:stop()
```